# Strange error some time flutter automatically stop and start execution

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
⡿ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -13
```

I have googled everywhere someone suggesting its due to an iOS device connected to the system but this is not my case, I'm running simulator. I tried by resetting and restarting the simulator.

Comment: When you googled to you come across this possible solution? https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/270#issuecomment-416861886

Comment: Yes, it does not work for me. it is just changed the error no 13 to 8
ideviceinfo returned an error:
ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -8

Answer (score 1):

Right now I figure out the temporary solution.
I do not know exactly what is the reason behind it. but the solution is **force quit all open terminal, simulator and emulator unplugged the all connected devices and then restart the simulator and emulator using IDE** whatever you are using to develop flutter application such as *Android Studio*, *Visual Studio Code*,(In my case I used *Visual Studio Code* to re-run the application and select debug and press the run button as suggested in below picture).

[image]